# The area of the region of the plane bounded by $(|x|,|y|)\leq1$ and $xy\leq\frac{1}{2}$ is $3+\ln 2.$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

The area of the region of the plane bounded by $(|x|,|y|)\leq1$ and $xy\leq\frac{1}{2}$ is $3+\ln 2.$

I know that the $(|x|,|y|)\leq1$ represents the inside of the square whose vertices are $(0,1),(1,0),(-1,0),(0,-1)$ and the $xy\leq \frac{1}{2} $ represents the rectangular hyperbola but these two curves do not cut each other.Then how will i find the required area?Please help me.

Comment: What do you mean by $(|x|,|y|)\le 1$? In particular, what binary operator is meant by the parentheses? Your description of that graph as the inside of a square better fits the relation $|x|+|y|\le 1$. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Also, how can a region be "bounded by" two solid regions? You could ask for the area of the *intersection* of your two given *regions*, or you could ask for the region *bounded* by the *curves* $|x|+|y|=1$, $xy=\frac 12$. But the question as given makes no sense.

Comment: Please dont mark it ''close'',members.I have given all details,which i had in my book.

Comment: Don't worry about the close votes. @RoryDaulton I think the close was a bit harsh, this is a maths question. I agree that I might write $|x|,\ |y|\le 1$ instead say but the notation couldn't mean anything else so one can power through. It's like people who use $]a,b[$ to denote $(a,b)$ - I actually see their point! Our notation looks like an ordered pair, but it isn't ambiguous in either case.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you correctly quoted the book, this is still a terrible question (for the reasons I gave). You should either improve the question or delete it. This question is salvageable, and if you salvage it I will withdraw my vote to close.

Comment: Are you sure the region wasn't supposed to be $|x| \le 1$, $|y| \le 1$?  The square you've found has side length $\sqrt{2}$, so its area is $2$, which is smaller than $3 + \ln 2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
The 4 lines are the square that you correctly identified.

The orange line is $xy=\frac{1}{2}$ and the black line is $xy=0.4<\frac{1}{2}$

You can see the region should be the square less corners whose $xy$ is *greater than* that of 0.5

Comment: Yes i drew this graph in desmos graphing calculator but still cant find out the answer after many attempts.@Alec Teal

Comment: @diya if you prove to me that you've actually tried I will help you further. You initially claimed for example that the curves don't intersect, I've disproved that. Take a picture of your workings and I'll take a look but I am not going to be tricked into doing homework.

Comment: No sir i dont want homework help,i want to learn the concept,i am giving my work,just wait.

Comment: @diya send me a comment (put `@alecteal` in it) when you're done.

Comment: Area enclosed between $|x|\leq 1,|y|\leq 1$ is 4 units.The area of the corner is $\int_{^1/2}^{1}1-\frac{1}{2x}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\ln 2$.Yes sir,i realised where mistake was.Now correct answer will come.Thank you@Alec Teal

Comment: @diya glad I could help, don't forget to upvote and tick!